# Implementation limitations of float.as_integer_ratio()

Tags: python, math

Recently, a correspondent mentioned [`float.as_integer_ratio()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex), new in Python 2.6, noting that typical floating point implementations are essentially rational approximations of real numbers. Intrigued, I had to try π:

```
>>> float.as_integer_ratio(math.pi);
(884279719003555L, 281474976710656L)
```

I was mildly surprised not to see the more [accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) result due to [Arima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arima_Yoriyuki),:

```
(428224593349304L, 136308121570117L)
```

For example, this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 36
print "python: ",Decimal(884279719003555) / Decimal(281474976710656)
print "Arima:  ",Decimal(428224593349304) / Decimal(136308121570117)
print "Wiki:    3.14159265358979323846264338327950288"
```

produces this output:

```
python:  3.14159265358979311599796346854418516
Arima:   3.14159265358979323846264338327569743
Wiki:    3.14159265358979323846264338327950288
```

Certainly, the result is correct given the precision afforded by 64-bit floating-point numbers, but it leads me to ask: How can I find out more about the implementation limitations of `as_integer_ratio()`? Thanks for any guidance.

Additional links: [Stern-Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) and [Python source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L1516).

Comment: The accepted answer is misleading. The `as_integer_ratio` method returns the numerator and denominator of a fraction whose value _exactly_ matches the value of the floating-point number passed to it. If you want a perfectly accurate representation of your float as a fraction, use `as_integer_ratio`. If you want a simplified _approximation_ with smaller denominator and numerator, look into `fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator`. IOW, `math.pi` is an approximation to π. But `884279719003555/281474976710656` is _not_ an approximation to `math.pi`; it's _exactly_ equal to it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Your point is well-taken; it clarifies this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076903/230513). Although the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076296/230513) could use some maintenance, it helped me see where my thinking had gone awry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm used by `as_integer_ratio` only [considers powers of 2 in the denominator](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.1/Objects/floatobject.c#L1534L1604). Here is a (probably) [better algorithm](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/8nqj1x7xmWg/umKDlL4N8xgJ).

Comment: Aha, `281474976710656 = 2^48`. Now I see where the values came from. Interesting to compare implementations: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/floatobject.c?revision=77139&view=markup

Comment: Saying the algorithm is not accurate is a flawed explanation.  `float.as_integer_ratio()` simply returns you a (numerator, denominator) pair which is *rigorously equal* to the floating-point number in question (that's why the denominator is a power of two, since standard floating-point numbers have a base-2 exponent). The loss in accuracy comes from the floating-point representation itself, *not* from float.as_integer_ratio() which is actually lossless.

Comment: IIUC, the algorithm is sufficiently accurate for a given floating-point precision. The genesis of the denominator is what puzzled me. The algorithm would never produce Arima's unique result, and there would be no point given the required precision.

Comment: Other algorithm you mentioned runs indefinitely for input `0.1 16` ([link](https://replit.com/@Prometheus3375/Double-as-integer-ratio#david-eppstein.c) to run)

Comment: Well, the problem was in the absence of check whether m[0][0] / m[1][0] is equal to original number. [Here](https://github.com/Prometheus3375/lua-std/blob/main/misc/as-integer-ratio/code.py#L4) is a fixed algorithm written in python.
You may easily add a limit to denominator as shown in the original algorithm.

Answer (score 9):

You get better approximations using

```
fractions.Fraction.from_float(math.pi).limit_denominator()
```

Fractions are included since maybe version 3.0.
However, math.pi doesn't have enough accuracy to return a 30 digit approximation.

Comment: `Fraction.from_float()` uses `float.as_integer_ratio()` under the hood. Both are exact, so both will give you the same answer. `limit_denominator` is only capable of decreasing precision, not increasing it.

Answer (score 5):

May I recommend [`gmpy`](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/)'s implementation of the [Stern-Brocot tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree):

```
>>> import gmpy
>>> import math
>>> gmpy.mpq(math.pi)
mpq(245850922,78256779)
>>> x=_
>>> float(x)
3.1415926535897931
>>>
```

again, the result is "correct within the precision of 64-bit floats" (53-bit "so-called" mantissas;-), but:

```
>>> 245850922 + 78256779
324107701
>>> 884279719003555 + 281474976710656
1165754695714211L
>>> 428224593349304L + 136308121570117
564532714919421L
```

...gmpy's precision is obtained so much **cheaper** (in terms of sum of numerator and denominator values) than Arima's, much less Python 2.6's!-)

Comment: I see the benefit. I've used GMP from Ada before, so `gmpy` will be handy. http://code.google.com/p/adabindinggmpmpfr/