# Python as_integer_ratio()

Tags: python, python-3.x, division

With the limitations of .as_integer_ratio(), what is the best way to reconcile a fraction such as 3/9? My program seems incapable of reconciling a .3 repeater.
Funnily enough, print(f1 + f2 / f1 - f2) comes out fine with test input 1 2 3 4, however print(f1 / f2) produces 6004799503160661/9007199254740992 instead of 2/3.
If I return a string instead, 2/3 comes out fine, but obviously 
print(f1 + f2 / f1 - f2) will not work.

```
import sys


class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        if self.b  == 0:
            print("Divide by zero")
            exit()
        x,y = (self.a/self.b).as_integer_ratio()
        return '{}/{}'.format(x, y)

    def __add__(self, two):
        x,y = (self.a/self.b + two.a/two.b).as_integer_ratio()
        return Fraction(x, y)

    def __sub__(self, two):
        x,y = (self.a/self.b - two.a/two.b).as_integer_ratio()
        return Fraction(x, y)

    def __truediv__(self, two):
        x,y = self.a*two.b, self.b*two.a
        x,y = (x/y).as_integer_ratio()
        return Fraction(x, y)
        # return '{}/{}'.format(x, y)

    def __mul__(self, two):
        x,y = ((self.a/self.b) * (two.a/two.b)).as_integer_ratio()
        return Fraction(x, y)

    def __mod__(self, two):
        x,y = self.a*two.b, self.b*two.a
        x,y = self.a/self.b, two.a/two.b
        x, y = (x%y).as_integer_ratio()
        return '{}/{}'.format(x, y)

    def __eq__(self, two):
        return self.a == two.a and self.b == two.b

f1 = Fraction(int(input()), int(input()))
f2 = Fraction(int(input()), int(input()))
print(f1)
print(f2)
print(f1 + f2)
print(f1 - f2)
print(f1 / f2)
print(f1 * f2)
print(f1 % f2)
print(f1 + f2 / f1 - f2)
print(f1 == f1)
```

Comment: Don't use the built-in `/`. If that worked, your whole Fraction class would be redundant. (It's already redundant if you consider `fractions.Fraction`, but it'd be even more redundant.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076290/implementation-limitations-of-float-as-integer-ratio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementation limitations of float.as\_integer\_ratio()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076290/implementation-limitations-of-float-as-integer-ratio)

Comment: You should call the properties `self.numerator` and `self.denominator` to make their roles clear. Then you need to implement all your operations without converting to floating point, because that loses precision. Go find a grade school math textbook and read the chapter on fractions.