# fractions.Fraction() returns different nom., denom. pair when parsing a float or its string representation

Tags: python, floating-point, fractions

I am aware of the nature of [floating point math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) but I still find the following surprising:

```
from fractions import Fraction

print(Fraction(0.2))       # -> 3602879701896397/18014398509481984
print(Fraction(str(0.2)))  # -> 1/5

print(Fraction(0.2)==Fraction(str(0.2)))  # returns False
print(0.2 == float(str(0.2)))             # but this returns True!
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html) I could not find anything that would explain that. It does state:

> ...In addition, any string that represents a finite value and is
>   accepted by the float constructor is also accepted by the Fraction
>   constructor...

but to me this implies a similar behavior to `float()` which I just do not see as shown above.

## Is there any explanation for this?

---

*It is important to note that the behavior shown above is not specific to the value (`0.2`) but rather general; everything I tried behaved the same way.*

---

Interestingly enough:

```
from fractions import Fraction


for x in range(1, 257):
    if Fraction(str(1/x))==Fraction(1/x):
        print(x)
```

prints only the **powers of 2** that are smaller than the selected upper bound:

```
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this two things are the same?

Comment: The reason is *exactly* as described in that question.

Comment: Well, `3602879701896397/18014398509481984` is equal to 0.2...

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I am not saying that the result is wrong; I am just surprised it is not the same

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, technically this is true: `3602879701896397/18014398509481985 = 0.2`

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I don't get what you are trying to say. Isn't that what I said?

Comment: no, look at the last digit. remember 7*5 = 35, so the denominator "should" end in 5.

Comment: try `0.2.as_integer_ratio()`, I think this is the relevant part from the docs, but it's rather brief:  "Beware that Fraction.from_float(0.3) is not the same value as Fraction(3, 10)"  https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.from_float

Comment: `Fraction` class treats `float/Decimal` in a different way then `str` argument. Have a look at [souce code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/fractions.py#L133) of it, specially [this regex](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/fractions.py#L45)

Comment: perhaps it's not counterintuitive that `fractions` module is more accurate with a string than with a float input. because floats are represented non-exactly in python, while strings need specific interpretation which can be made more accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the `def __new__():` implementation in [fractions.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fractions.py), if a string is given:

The regex `_RATIONAL_FORMAT` ( see link if you are interested in the parsing part) puts out `numerator` as `0` and `decimal` as `2`

> Start quote from [fractions.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/fractions.py) source, with comments by me

```
elif isinstance(numerator, str):
    # Handle construction from strings.
    m = _RATIONAL_FORMAT.match(numerator)
    if m is None:
        raise ValueError('Invalid literal for Fraction: %r' %
                         numerator)
    numerator = int(m.group('num') or '0')       # 0
    denom = m.group('denom')                     
    if denom:                                    # not true for your case
        denominator = int(denom)
    else:                                        # we are here
        denominator = 1
        decimal = m.group('decimal')             # yep: 2
        if decimal:
            scale = 10**len(decimal)             # thats 10^1
            numerator = numerator * scale + int(decimal)    # thats 0 * 10^1+0 = 10
            denominator *= scale                 # thats 1*2
        exp = m.group('exp')  
        if exp:                                  # false
            exp = int(exp)
            if exp >= 0:
                numerator *= 10**exp
            else:
                denominator *= 10**-exp
    if m.group('sign') == '-':                   # false
        numerator = -numerator

else:
    raise TypeError("argument should be a string "
                    "or a Rational instance")
```

> end quote from source

So `'0.2'` is parsed to `2 / 10 = 0.2` *exactly*, not its nearest float approximation wich my calculater puts out at `0,20000000000000001110223024625157`

Quintessential: they are not simply using `float( yourstring )` but are parsing and calculating the string itself, that is why both differ.

If you use the same constructor and provide a `float` or `decimal` the constructor uses the builtin `as_integer_ratio()` to get numerator and denominator as representation of that number.

The closest the float representation comes to 0.2 is 0,20000000000000001110223024625157 which is exactly what the `as_integer_ratio()` method returns nominator and denominator for.

As [eric-postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) 
 and [mark-dickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) pointed out, this float value is limited by its binary representations to "close to 0.2". When put into `str()` will be truncated to exact `'0.2'` - hence the differences between

```
print(Fraction(0.2))       # -> 3602879701896397/18014398509481984
print(Fraction(str(0.2)))  # -> 1/5
```

Comment: your answer has been very helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer describes part of why `print(Fraction(str(0.2)))` prints “1/5” (it omits the fact that `str(0.2)` produces “0.2”) but does not address why `print(Fraction(0.2))` prints “3602879701896397/18014398509481984”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - it prints 3602879701896397/18014398509481984  because that is what `float(0.2).as_integer_ratio()` returns - wich is handled in the last 3 lines of this answer? should I state it better?

Comment: I see. It is not clear that the last sentence discusses `print(Fraction(0.2))`. Generally, why take so much text and code to explain that “0.2” is analyzed to produce 1/5? That is a normally expected result; it does not really require explanation. There are really just two complications in the OP’s question: In `Fraction(0.2)`, the source text `0.2` does not produce a floating-pont value that is exactly 0.2, and, in `str(0.2)`, it does produce a string that is “0.2” even though the argument to `str` is not exactly 0.2. Once those are explained, everything else follows.

Comment: The `float.as_integer_ratio()` method is _perfectly_ accurate. It returns the numerator and denominator of a fraction whose value is _precisely_ equal to the float that it's given. The inaccuracy that you're referring to is introduced when parsing the `0.2` literal in the source code to the corresponding binary64 float. `as_integer_ratio` has nothing to do with it. Please read the comments on the top answer to the question that you link to.

Comment: @MarkDickinson reworded it, could you take another look?

Answer (score 3):

In `print(Fraction(0.2))`, the source text `0.2` is converted to a floating-point value. The result of this conversion is exactly 0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125, or 3602879701896397/18014398509481984. This value is then passed to `Fraction`, which produces the same value represented as a rational number.

In `print(Fraction(str(0.2)))`, `0.2` is again converted to a floating-point value, yielding the number above. Then `str` converts it to a string. In current Python versions, when a floating-point value is converted to a string, Python does not generally produce the exact mathematical value. Instead, it produces the just enough digits so that converting the string back to floating-point produces the input number. In this case, that results in “0.2”. So the string “0.2” is passed to `Fraction`. Then `Fraction` analyzes “0.2” and determines it is 1/5.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the last digit in the denominator. It appears the `fractions` module takes this into consideration when storing the object internally, but when used in operations python can round.

```
from fractions import Fraction

Fraction(3602879701896397, 18014398509481985)  == Fraction(1, 5)   # True
Fraction(3602879701896397, 18014398509481984) == Fraction(1, 5)    # False
3602879701896397 / 18014398509481985 == 0.2  # True
3602879701896397 / 18014398509481984 == 0.2  # True
```

Now the question of why the `fractions` module chooses an approximation (i.e. `18014398509481984` instead of correct `18014398509481985`) is not one I can answer.

Comment: When you give a `float` or `decimals` as constructor argument  fractions.py uses the build in `.as_integer_ratio()` to get the nominator/denominator wich is an approximation according to [implementation-limitations-of-float-as-integer-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076290/implementation-limitations-of-float-as-integer-ratio)

Comment: thank you, this is an actual explanation. you'd think `fractions` module would align output from equivalent `str()` and `float` inputs though.